# Sitio para preguntas basadas en opiniones

Tags: discusión

En lo personal, lamento que [preguntas como esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1991/169) no sean apropiadas para SO. Sin embargo lo acepto, pues las respuestas se basarán en opiniones.

¿Saben ustedes si existe algún sitio o comunidad donde puedan ser aceptables este tipo de preguntas?

Comment: Una opción podría ser preguntar en el chat (aunque para ello se necesita un mínimo de reputación).

Comment: La pregunta referida ha sido eliminada ¿sobre que tema era?

Comment: En un comantario a una respuesta preguntas por un foro en español. Considerando mi comentario anterior y lo mencionado previamente en este me parece que aún para una pregunta para Meta es demasiado amplia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que los foros son mas adecuados para ese tipo de preguntas, recientemente encontré esta [página](http://www.slant.co/) en donde tratan justamente ese tipo de preguntas.

Comment: Se ve bastante adecuado para preguntas de opinión, aunque no sé cómo le hacen para que la gente no divague y no escriba demasiado. Ahora, ¿en español? XD ☺️

Comment: Hasta ahora solo le he usado para consulta y en español ni idea.

Answer (score 4):

Te recomiendo una que siempre leo: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/)
Tal y como dices, basada en opiniones.
Que tengan buen día, bendiciones!

Answer (score 0):

No sólo existe un sitio o comunidad, en mi opinión existen demasiados por lo que te sugiero usar **Google** o algún otro de los buscadores principales, así como también los buscadores de las **Facebook**, **Google+**, **LinkedIn** y cualquier otro servicio web de redes sociales.

Palabras clave sugeridas

- debate
- opinión
- discusión
- controversia
- foro
- sitio
- espacio
- comunidad
- registro

Answer (score -2):

Interesante pregunta, y hablan de basa en opiniones basadas en programación o opiniones en general?

Porque si resulta un poco triste que cataloguen la pregunta cómo inadecuada al preguntar la manera adecuada o en caso de como proceder y cosas por el estilo que se muchos podrían aportar, pero debido a las consideraciones que se decidieron tomar, no se podrán efectuar dar..